# Setting NSBox's setContentView with NSImageView not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSBox set up in my main view that accepts drag and drop. We store the URL into str. We then load the image and add it to the content view of NSBox.

```
 imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 390, 150)];
 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
 NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingURL:imageURL];
 [imageView setImage:image];
 [self setContentView:imageView];
```

However, this doesn't do anything. The image is not displayed in the nsbox.

Another oddity. At first I was trying to add the NSImageView via interface builder, but the only image container they had was IKImageView... Is this odd? Isn't NSImageView more ubiquitous? I mainly develop on iOS, so I have the version from the ios developer site.

Any thoughts?

Edit: I should also add, when I was using IKImageView in IB, the image would show up.
Edit2: I've also tried just taking the initWithFrame out and replacing it with just init, no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using initByReferencingURL to get the NSImage. This doesn't work for local files, so instead I used initByReferencingFile and everything worked out well!